# Using a function to loop through an array and push object into empty array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm trying create a function called addToList that loops through var movies and pushes everything to my empty array var movieList. Here is my code...

```
    var movies = [
      { title: 'matrix', id: 0},
      { title:'the dark knight', id: 1},
      { title:'a beautiful mind', id: 2},
      { title:'american pie', id: 3}
    ]

    function addToList(movies) {
      var movieList = {};

      for(var key in movies)
        movieList.push(movies[key])
      }

      return movieList

    addToList(movies)
```

I'm trying to get a return of:

```
[
  '{title:matrix, id:0}',
  '{title:the dark knight, id:1}',
  '{title:a beautiful mind, id:2}',
  '{title:american pie, id:3}'
]
```

I'm not sure why my code isn't working.

Comment: Look at error(s) thrown in browser dev tools console. Can't push to an object .. `{}` ... and error should give you a clue. Assuming you get to that error

Comment: So you want to just duplicate the first array, but convert the objects in that first array to strings?

Comment: I fixed the formatting on your code, which should make at least one problem with it starkly apparent. Using proper formatting can help show some of these things, but posting code in a stack overflow question that isn't even syntactically valid (i.e. won't run at all) is usually a no-go unless you're specifically asking about syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map()`, `JSON.stringify()` and `.replace(/"|'/g,"")` you could get your desired output.

```js
var movies = [
    { title: 'matrix', id: 0},
    { title:'the dark knight', id: 1},
    { title:'a beautiful mind', id: 2},
    { title:'american pie', id: 3}
  ];

  movies = movies.map(o=>JSON.stringify(o).replace(/"|'/g,""))

  console.log(movies)
```

Your code does not work because you are trying to push into an object, if you change `movieList = {}` for `movieList = []` should work, but not as your desired output which is an array of strings similar to a [JSON](https://json.org/example.html). that is why you could turn each object into a JSON and then remove the quotes, as your example.

```js
var movies = [
    { title: 'matrix', id: 0},
    { title:'the dark knight', id: 1},
    { title:'a beautiful mind', id: 2},
    { title:'american pie', id: 3}
  ]

  function addToList(movies) {
    var movieList = [];

    for(var key in movies){
      movieList.push(movies[key])//<-- objects into an array
    }

    return movieList
}

  console.log(addToList(movies))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of syntax error in your code, the return statement need to be inside the function , & also never use `for..in` to iterate an array

```js
var movies = [{
    title: 'matrix',
    id: 0
  },
  {
    title: 'the dark knight',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    title: 'a beautiful mind',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    title: 'american pie',
    id: 3
  }
]

function addToList(movies) {
  var movieList = [];
  movies.forEach((item) => {
    movieList.push(JSON.stringify(item))

  })
  return movieList
}


console.log(addToList(movies))
```

Comment: Might also mention that you can't `.push` onto an object.

Comment: This does what the OP "says" he wants but doesn't output the same output the OP has "shown". Not sure if this is right or not until OP clarifies desired results.

Comment: `.forEach()` + `.push()` = `.map()`

Comment: Why advocate for using a loop and a function to copy an array? Seems like `movies.slice()` is a better alternative.

Comment: @Andreas I think OP want to use the variable, that is not clear here,

Comment: @MarkMeyer I agree with you , there are numerous better way to do , but in my opinion the solution should be close to what OP has done

Comment: thanks everyone. I'm reading your comments now and reviewing my errors. apologies for the lame syntax errors. guess ive been starting at this one for too long. my mistake.

Comment: @6Ortiz Please also clarify exactly what you want the output to be. Do you really want the objects in the array to become strings?